# Javascript setTimeout delays - I've tried and tried but this just won't slow down

Tags: javascript, html

This code is supposed to change the five images one at a time. I won't go into details but it HAS to use an array to control the images. The problem is, there is no delay between the image changing. I've looked into problems that others have come across with setTimeout but can't see that I've done that part wrong.

I know there are probably much neater ways of doing this but I'm trying to keep it really simple using easy to explain chunks of code.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>


    <script>
        var array=[0,0,0,0,0];

        function updatelights() {
            if (array[0]==1) {
                document.images.light1.src="lighton.png";
            }
            else {
                document.images.light1.src="lightoff.png";
            }
            if (array[1]==1) {
                document.images.light2.src="lighton.png";
            }
            else {
                document.images.light2.src="lightoff.png";
            }
            //other if statements here as above
        }

        function animatelights() {
            light1on();
            setTimeout(updatelights,1000);
            light2on();
            setTimeout(updatelights,1000);
            light3on();
            setTimeout(updatelights,1000);
            light4on();
            setTimeout(updatelights,1000);
            light5on();
            setTimeout(updatelights,1000);
        }

        function light1on() {
            array=[1,0,0,0,0];
        }
        function light2on() {
            array=[0,1,0,0,0];
        }
        function light3on() {
            array=[0,0,1,0,0];
        }
        function light4on() {
            array=[0,0,0,1,0];
        }
        function light5on() {
            array=[0,0,0,0,1];
        }

    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <!-- This is an HTML table with five columns. There is an image in each column-->
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <td><img name="light1" src="lightoff.png"></td>
            <td><img name="light2" src="lightoff.png"></td> 
            <td><img name="light3" src="lightoff.png"></td>
            <td><img name="light4" src="lightoff.png"></td>
            <td><img name="light5" src="lightoff.png"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <!-- This is an HTML button -->
    <button type = "button" onclick="animatelights()"> Animate </button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use a debugger and it will show you exactly what is going on. hint: `setTimeout` doesn't block.

Comment: setTimeout does not pause the execution. It is not a sleep, so all the lines after it still run.

Answer (score 4):

When I see this:

```
    light1on();
    setTimeout(updatelights,1000);
    light2on();
    setTimeout(updatelights,1000);
    light3on();
    setTimeout(updatelights,1000);
    light4on();
    setTimeout(updatelights,1000);
    light5on();
    setTimeout(updatelights,1000);
```

It seems like you expect things to go line by line, which it does but the code doesn't get executed in that order. setTimeout is non blocking meaning that the actual order of that code will be:

```
light1on();
light2on();
light3on();
light4on();
light5on();
```

then a second later all the updatelights get called:

```
  updatelights(); //from setTimeout
  updatelights(); //from setTimeout
  updatelights(); //from setTimeout
  updatelights(); //from setTimeout
  updatelights(); //from setTimeout
```

So the solution should be something like this:

```
var arr = [light1on, light2on, light3on, light4on, light5on];
var i = 1;

arr[0]();
var si = setInterval(function(){
  if(i >= arr.length){
    clearInterval(si);
  }
  arr[i]();
  i++
  updatelights();
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout` is not a sleep function.

It puts the function you pass to it onto a queue to be called later on when:

- the specified amount of time has passed *and*
- the JS event loop isn't busy running another function

You are calling each of your `lightNon` functions one after the other and then, after about a second, calling `updatelights` 5 times.

The general way to approach this would be to:

1. Replace your `lightNon` functions with an array of functions (or, better, a function that used an array of data)
2. Create a variable to track which index of that array you want to deal with next
3. Use `setInterval` to, every second, run a function that:

   - sets the array
   - calls the update function
   - increments the variable tracking the index

Comment: Gotcha! Now I understand why it isn't working, that's always good. I'll scratch my head about using the setInterval function.

Comment: Not to mention he is using global variables... I tested on chrome's Console and only the last light was on. Well, of course sir.

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of unnecessary code. If I were trying to learn this stuff from your example I would be thoroughly confused. I took the liberty of simplifying your example.

[Here's a JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/39qj3hc0/)

**HTML (I added a class name to the images)**

```
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <td><img class='rotateImage' name="light1" src="http://antigonishoptical.ca/images/black-dot.png"></td>
        <td><img class='rotateImage' name="light2" src="http://antigonishoptical.ca/images/black-dot.png"></td> 
        <td><img class='rotateImage' name="light3" src="http://antigonishoptical.ca/images/black-dot.png"></td>
        <td><img class='rotateImage' name="light4" src="http://antigonishoptical.ca/images/black-dot.png"></td>
        <td><img class='rotateImage' name="light5" src="http://antigonishoptical.ca/images/black-dot.png"></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<!-- This is an HTML button -->
<button type = "button" onclick="animatelights()"> Animate </button>
```

**And the JS..**

```
// URL for the on light
var lightsOn = "http://info.sonicretro.org/images/1/1b/Reddot.gif";

// URL for the off light
var lightsOff = "http://antigonishoptical.ca/images/black-dot.png";

// The active light (you don't need an array since you only have one light on at a time)
var activeLight = 0;

function animatelights() {

    // Get an array of your images by adding a class name to them
    var lights = document.getElementsByClassName('rotateImage');

    // Loop thru the image and turn all the lights off
    for(var i=0; i<lights.length; i++) lights[i].src = lightsOff;

    // Then turn on the light that is currently active
    lights[activeLight].src = lightsOn;

    // increment the active light variable so the next light lights up next time
    activeLight++;

    // Check to see if we've gone through all inputs. If we have the cirrent index won't exists, 
    // so we reset it back to zero
    if('undefined' === typeof lights[activeLight]) activeLight = 0;

    // After three seconds, call the function again recursively
    setTimeout(animatelights, 3000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> This is wrong approch.

`setTimeout()` does not pause or stop execution.It execute some code after given time. You can use callback function to prevent from execution some thing like this:

```
 function second()
 {
   alert("ok");
 }

setTimeout(second,100);
```

```js
function secondFunction() {
  alert("after 1 second");
}

setTimeout(secondFunction, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you're changing the `array` at once.

You want to call `light2on` (etc) after a delay (`setTimeout`). The correct would be call it in the `setTimeout` callback function. You must call `light[number]on` before `updatelights`.
Do this for each one:

```
setTimeout(function(){light2on();updatelights()},1000)
```

But a interval would be more faster, and it's not needed to create these functions and global variables.